# Android GridLayout - How to increase the spacing between columns or rows?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio, android-gridlayout

[image: image with numeric buttons]
This is just a portion of the background image. I have a gridlayout with 4 rows and 3 columns. These buttons in the layout (included just 3 for now) need to superimpose a background image which has a numeric keypad. I need to put the buttons exactly to fit these parts of image which have the numbers and will then make it transparent, so clicking on a number corresponds to clicking the actual button. Tried several methods but to no avail. I am not able to exactly fit them. Increasing the spacing between might help but just not able to get at it. Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your description will be enough for us to help you with the problem. Do you have an illustration you could include?

Comment: @BartekLipinski Just modified my question and included a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be exceedingly difficult to make sure the buttons fit the superimposed image exactly on devices with different screen sizes and different pixel densities. You are much better off having the user tap on the button itself. Use white for the text color and make a single rounded rectangle to use as the background of each button.

In `src/main/res/drawable/orange_round_rect.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/orange_button" />
</shape>
```

Anything that isn't the button can be added elsewhere, e.g. as a background of the GridLayout.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Unfortunately I am given just the image for the entire screen background and cannot do much to modify it. But I will find out if it is possible to get a bg image without these numerics and instead get individual button images to put on the buttons directly. In general I would like to know, if there is any good source of learning how direct images are used for the background screens with portions of image being used as UI components, Thanks!

Comment: @Ganga I personally haven't done that, and I think it's very rare outside of maybe an immersive game that wants a specific atmosphere with all of its UI. If you aren't building that, I suggest talking with your designers about Google's design guidelines, so that your app behaves the way users have learned to expect from on all the other apps they use. Also, sometimes the platform just doesn't have an easy way to do things; this is one of them, and it's perfectly reasonable to ask for an alternative so that you can spend more time on features that matter.